# Better practice of return statement in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, comparative-review, react.js

What is a better practice, to have an implicit return and something big inside the curly braces `{project.name === 'default' ? 'Unassigned' : project.name}`

```
  createProjectList(userProjects) {
    const projectsList = userProjects.map((project) => (
      <option key={project.id} value={project.id}>
        {project.name === 'default' ? 'Unassigned' : project.name}
      </option>
    ))
    projectsList.push(<option key={'all'} value={'all'}>{'Show All'}</option>)
    return projectsList
  }
```

Or is better to not have an implicit return and put that inside a constant?

```
  createProjectList(userProjects) {
    const projectsList = userProjects.map((project) => {
      const projectName = project.name === 'default' ? 'Unassigned' : project.name
      return (
        <option key={project.id} value={project.id}>{projectName}</option>        
      )
    })
    projectsList.push(<option key={'all'} value={'all'}>{'Show All'}</option>)
    return projectsList
  }
```

Comment: Is this actual code used or are those pieces of code just to illustrate?

Comment: Simple rule is "Keep it simple". Adding a constant when you can clearly do without is adding complexity for no reason or benefit and is thus  not best practice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I personally would prefer the first one as it prevents you from having to define a variable and then immediately garbage collect it, which means it will be a little faster.

Additionally, with the first one you can [omit the parentheses](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions#Function_body):

```
const projectsList = userProjects.map(project => 
  <option key={project.id} value={project.id}>
    {project.name === 'default' ? 'Unassigned' : project.name}
  </option>
)
```

*Note that you should keep the parentheses if it makes the function easier to read, in this case, in my opinion, it does not.*